# Animate single item in datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I am trying to run an animation on a listbox when an item is updated.
I have the item working well with the observablecollection (MVVM) and the item is updating perfectly.
I have set this code to the listbox to run an animation BUT it's animating all items in the listbox and I want only the item that has actually been updated.

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded" SourceName="dockProjects">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myAnimatedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="Orange" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="0:0:4" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Any help would be gratefully accpeted. Thanks Scott

Comment: And how do you know which item was updated? Because my idea would be to use viewmodel to notify which one is updated. And then in a view you could create a data trigger with binding.

Comment: Yes. not sure. I am thinking it through now. Thanks for comments

Answer (score 0):

This is just a pseudo answer because the answer to your question is too broad and would take too long to cover in detail. The answer in its simplest form is this... you need to manually access the relevant `UIElement` in code and call the `BeginAnimation` method to start the `Animation`. Hopefully, this is all you would need.

In its most complex, this call could be in an `AnimatedPanel` base class and your data type classes could have special custom animation properties. For example, I have such a set up and to perform a slide animation as an element is removed from a collection, you have to delay the actual removal, perform the animation and *then* actually remove the item.

Comment: sorry been away. I will comment as soon as I can. appreciate it